# Create a static member for the purpose of condition/wait java

Tags: java, concurrency

Is it possible to create a static member in a class that would react (if its [`wait`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) method is called), correctly for threads which do not share the same instance of the class (would they be able to notify each other with [`notifyAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll%28%29) using the static member field)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store a single instance in a static field of a class that any number of threads can `wait` upon. Where the instance is stored does not matter. The key is that all threads have access to the same instance--be it from a static field/method or a singleton service object or a static local variable.

```
public class MakeMeWait {
    private static Object semaphore = new Object();

    public static void waitPlease() {
        semaphore.wait();
    }

    public static void wakePlease() {
        semaphore.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

While this example uses the built-in Java `wait` and `notifyAll` methods, you're far better off using the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package rather than rolling your own multithreading solutions.

Comment: thanks this clarifies the problem. I don't see how there is no difference in storing that semaphore object in a static field. What if every thread getting used had a different instance of MakeMeWait? Then an instance field for semaphore would work or not?

Comment: "This is no different than storing the instance in a non-static field." Yes it is. It's static. I would just delete that sentence from your answer, which is otherwise fine.

Comment: @EJP - How does `wait`ing on an instance stored in a static field differ from an instance field differ from a local variable? They are all instances of an object; where they are stored doesn't affect synchronization.

Comment: Of course it doesn't but it affects its visibility to other threads, which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @EJB - Does my edit help to clarify the importance of a shared instance?

Comment: Using a String literal should be avoided as some other class could get access to it through string interning. A `new Object()` initialized in proper scope is most times the best choice for an object to wait on.

Comment: @oksayt - Thanks, for some reason I was thinking you couldn't instantiate `Object` directly, but of course you can.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention it should be `final` too, to prevent against the value getting accidentally changed and causing threads to lock on different objects.

Comment: @oksayt - It's private and controlled by the class, and we don't have enough information to know if it might need to change to a new object. I try to include the minimum constraints necessary to solve the problem in example code to avoid confusion.